# Can echo specify a floating-point number?

Tags: php, printf, echo

I can do this using printf()

`printf ("Total amount of order is %.2f", $total);`

Can I do the same using echo, or I have to use printf()?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this..

```
$total= 100.123;
echo "Total amount of order is ". round($total, 2);
```

**Output**:

```
Total amount of order is 100.12
```

Comment: Nice and short ! Thanks a lot next2u!

Comment: If the total comes to a round number, it won't output to 2 decimal places. round(120.00,2) = 120, not 120.00. Same for single digits, 120.20 would become 120.2.

Answer (score 4):

Using echo alone? No. You would include `number_format` in the echoed string for the same functionality.

```
echo "Total amount of order is ".number_format($total,2);
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks James!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify format using echo.

However if you need to assign result to string, you can simple use `sprintf` function:

```
$var = sprintf ("Total amount of order is %.2f", $total);
echo $var;
```

Comment: Oh I can use sprintf() too. Thanks Marcin!